# Is the best way to search for an empty string just ' '?

Tags: mysql, null

I am searching for fields with empty strings in a mySQL database. Is the best way simply:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Versions
WHERE vers = ' ';
```

Or is there a function or better practice for this? A lot of data was imported in, and it turned into empty strings here, though the default is NULL if there is no data entered into that field.

Just getting started here, thank you for your patience!

Comment: A space `' '` is not an empty string. `''` is.

Comment: `WHERE vers='' OR vers IS NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this if you want just empty Strings not nulls

```
SELECT * FROM Versions WHERE vers IS NOT NULL and vers = '';
```

and if you want both nulls and Empty Strings it would be like this :

```
 SELECT * FROM Versions WHERE vers IS NULL or vers = '';
```